# Entry point to a Flow From a Result Search Page

Tags: mobile

I have search result page that lists vendors (see below). I want to add an entry point for requesting an invoice.

[image]

I want to collect suggestions on how to model this entry point. The best I have so far is a button that says "Request an Invoice" below the the 3 lines text.

Extra information: Clicking on the card takes you to the detail page.

Comment: Can you select multiple vendors to do a bulk request of invoices or do you have to click on each button to request a single invoice? And is there also the same button to request an invoice in the detailed vendor page?

Comment: There will be a request an invoice in the detail page. I didn't think of a bulk request. That's something I am open to explore. Do you have suggestions on how to model that?

Comment: I am not sure how you have designed and implemented the search results page, but a common way to allow bulk actions is to create a table and allow users to select items from the table, and have a button at the top or bottom of the table with specific actions. See an example from this question about mixing bulk actions with single actions: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/117243/whats-a-good-pattern-for-mixing-bulk-able-actions-and-single-actions